# One .ashx generic handler for all file types?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler, file-type

I've gone through the basic MSDN information and a few tutorials.  From what I've learned so far, I have been able to make two .ashx handlers, that I call ImageHandler.ashx and PDFHandler.ashx.  They do what you would expect: return images or PDFs, respectively.  For both of these handlers, in the `ProcessRequest` method, I'm setting `context.Response.ContentType` to "image/jpeg" and "application/pdf", respectively, then writing the result with `context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)` So far this works just fine.

However, I want to allow a user to have the ability to download any file, regardless of type.  Do I really need to create a different Handler for every file type?

Can I just have one .ashx file and then have a switch statement based on the file type (which I would get via substring of the filename)?  Even if I do that, what about file types that aren't standard, like say .xyz files?  What do I set the `content.Response.ContentType` to in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not need multiple handlers, *especially* if the fundamental operation is the same. Yes, you can use any kind of logic you want to decide what to set the response content-type to. For something you don't know, use `application/octet-stream`. You should also consider setting the "content-disposition" header, which gives you a chance to suggest whether it should be shown "inline" (i.e. in the browser), or prompted as a download - and what the logical filename is (rather than some ashx page).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Working perfectly now.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `Content-type: application/octet-stream` and let the browser handle what to do based on the file extension.

Comment: Two great answers, sorry I could only pick one.

Comment: I think nowadays you should set the security header [X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options) and set an explicit content type for each type of file you serve.